# I have to print array data into the table

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have to print user defined array data into the table. Once user clicks on Add button.
I'm able to print data out of table. But I want to print it inside the table.

**Here's my code:**

```js
var data = new Array(); // blank array declaration

function check_info() {
    var text = document.getElementById("enter").value;
    var txtage = document.getElementById("age").value;

    if (text == "" || txtage == "") {
        console.log("Check Function load");
        alert('Please fill the Field');
        return false;
    } else {
        return display();
    }
}

function display() {
    var str1 = document.getElementById("enter").value;
    var str2 = document.getElementById("age").value;

    document.getElementById('enter').value = '';
    document.getElementById('age').value = '';

    if ((str1 == "" || str1.length == 0) && (str2 == "" || str2.length == 0)) {
        return false;
    }
    data.push(str1);
    data.push(str2);
    document.getElementById("str1").children[0].innerHTML += "<li>" + data[data.length - 1] + "</li>";
    document.getElementById("str2").children[1].innerHTML += "<li>" + data[data.length - 1] + "</li>"

}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <lable>Enter name : </lable> <input type="text" id="enter" required/>
  <lable>Enter age : </lable> <input type="text" id="age" required/> <input type="button" value="Add" onclick="check_info()">
  <div id='str'>
    <ol></ol>
  </div>
  <table align='center' cellspacing=2 cellpadding=5 id="data_table" border=1>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th> Name</th>
        <th> Age</th>
        <th> Action</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

I want to print the data inside the table.
Can anyone tell me what exactly the issue is?

Comment: Can you show us your HTML, please?

Comment: try making a globar variable... `data = new Array();` --remove the 'var'

Comment: <body>

    <lable>Enter name : </lable>
    <input type="text" id="enter" required/>
    <lable>Enter age : </lable>
    <input type="text" id="age" required/>
    <input type="button" value="Add" onclick="check_info()">
    <div id='str'><ol></ol></div>

    <table align='center' cellspacing=2 cellpadding=5 id="data_table" border=1>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th> Name</th>
                <th> Age</th>
                <th> Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>

</body>
</html>

Answer (score 0):

The error in your code is that you are inserting the data into the wrong element because your reference id is incorrect. Also, you should practice inserting your table rows inside a `<tbody>` element. Finally, unless there is another reason for the array, you do not need it.

Also, you should consider using a JS library like [jQuery](https://www.w3schools.com/JQuery/). Your code will be much simpler and cleaner than vanilla JS.

```js
let tableArray = [];

function check_info() {
  var text = document.getElementById("name").value;
  var txtage = document.getElementById("age").value;

  if (text == "" || txtage == "") {
    console.log("Check Function load");
    alert('Please fill the Field');
    return false;
  } else {
    return display();
  }
}

function display() {
  var str1 = document.getElementById("name").value;
  var str2 = document.getElementById("age").value;
  var tbodyElem = document.getElementById("tbody");

  document.getElementById('name').value = '';
  document.getElementById('age').value = '';

  if ((str1 == "" || str1.length == 0) && (str2 == "" || str2.length == 0)) {
    return false;
  }
  
  tableArray.push([[str1], [str2]]);
  tbodyElem.innerHTML += `<tr><td>${str1}</td><td>${str2}</td><td></td></tr>`
  console.log(tableArray);
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <lable>Enter name : </lable> <input type="text" id="name" required/>
  <lable>Enter age : </lable> <input type="text" id="age" required/> <input type="button" value="Add" onclick="check_info()">
  <table align='center' cellspacing=2 cellpadding=5 id="data_table" border=1>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th> Name</th>
        <th> Age</th>
        <th> Action</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tbody">
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: Please accept and upvote my answer if it helped you. Thanks.

Comment: @Eknow -- Your code is usable but I want same thing with array data in tabular form

Comment: Do you mean something like this: `['test name', 10]`? Could you clarify the structure of the contents of the array.

Comment: global array declaration -- var data = []; I have to store user inputs in array and then after print into the table form.

Comment: So, you need the global array for a separate table form  or the same table before? Could you clarify that. Thanks.

Comment: I have updated the code, the data are now being pushed inside an array in a tabular form ([[name], [age]])

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to keep the code DRY and clean without using any overloaded libraries...  You should also consider removing the cellspacing and cellpadding attributes from the table since they are deprecated in html5 use instead css to style the table.

```
var data = [];
function check_info()
{
    // without the trim function a user can easily 
    // bypass this typing just whitespaces. 
    // do you really want the age to be any character? 
    var enter = document.getElementById("enter").value.trim();
    var age = document.getElementById("age").value.trim();

    if (enter == "" || age == "")
    {
        console.log("Check Function load");
        alert('Please fill the Field');
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        // If there is no need to call the display function elsewhere, 
        // you can just paste its code directly here to prevent
        // unnecessary function call
        return display(enter, age);
    }
}


function display(enter, age)
{
    data.push(enter, age);
    document.getElementById("data_table").innerHTML += "<tr><td>" + enter + "</td><td>" + age + "</td> <td></td></tr>";

}
```